# canonical vs dualizing bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is well known that for smooth projective varieties over a field $k$ the dualizing sheaf is isomorphic to the canonical sheaf. My question is now if this holds for the relative case assuming both schemes in question are smooth projective varieties?